# Parsing string into dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

i would like to transform in an elegent way this kind of string :

`"{lastname=Oba, firstname=Bar}"`

to

```
var person = [];
person["firstName"] = "Bar";
person["lastName"] = "Oba";
```

I try with JSON parse but not working, 
i don't know how to that without dirty spliting

Comment: It is not [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) hence why JSON.parse does not work

Comment: The top item is just a string, it's not JSON hence why JSON.parse isn't working

Comment: OK it isn't JSON, but has it a simple parser ?

Comment: You need to split it and/or parse it with a regular expression. You need to write the parser OR have whatever is spitting out that code produce proper JSON to start!

Comment: Have something against `split()`?

Comment: The best solution is to fix the code that creates the string to create correct JSON.

Comment: Replace '=' with ':', which will give you a valid *parsable* JSON.

Comment: @user1514042 No, that's not enough. JSON requires double quotes around the keys and values.

Comment: Ah sure wrap them up with the double quotes then!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should easily parse this.

```
function myParser(str) {
    return str.slice(1, -1).split(',').map(function(el) {
        return el.trim()
    }).map(function(el) {
        return el.split('=')
    }).reduce(function(result, pair) {
        result[pair[0].trim()] = pair[1].trim();
        return result
    }, {});
}
```

It will work as expected only for small group of properties and datas, but figuring these cases and fixing that behaviour is leaved as exercise for reader.

Answer (score 2):

Algorithm:
splitting string by `,` you'll get a list of `A=B` pairs, then split each pair of the list by `=` and form dictionary:

*Python*

```py
s = "{lastname=Oba, firstname=Bar}"

l = s[1:-1].split(",")
d = {}
for e in l:
    a = e.split("=")
    d[a[0].strip()] = a[1].strip()
```

*JavaScript*

```
var s = "{lastname=Oba, firstname=Bar}";

var l = s.slice(1,-1).split(',');
var d = {};
for (var i in l) {
    var a = l[i].split('=');
    d[a[0].trim()] = a[1].trim();
}
```